# How to count lines

Tags: c#

how do i count the line in log file and create a new log files of it?

Below is my log file :

```
DDD.CGLOG
    ID|AFP|DATE|FOLDER
    1|DDD|20181204|B
    2|DDD|20181104|B
    3|DDD|20181004|B

FFF.CGLOG
   ID|AFP|DATE|FOLDER
    1|FFF|20181204|B
    2|FFF|20181104|B

WWW.CGLOG
   ID|AFP|DATE|FOLDER
    1|WWW|20181204|B
```

i want to count the line and create a new log file as below :

```
 DDD_QTY.Log
    AFP|QTY
    DDD|3

EEE_QTY.Log
    AFP|QTY
    EEE|2

WWW_QTY.Log
    AFP|QTY
    WWW|1
```

Below is what i have tried. I have managed to get the count from each log file inside the folder, now i just need to write the count into a new log file using a same name with existing log file.

```
string[] ori_Files = Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\Work\FLP Code\test", "*.CGLOG*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        foreach (var file in ori_Files)
        {
            using (StreamReader file1 = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                string line;
                int count = 0;

                while ((line = file1.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                    count++;

                }

                Console.WriteLine(count);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Your code doesn't do anywhere near to what you describe, I'm afraid. For each iteration of the inner loop, you're reading another line from the file, and then continuing the loop if the length of that particular line in the file is greater than `i`.

Comment: Also, you haven't mentioned if AFP will always be "DDD", and in case it is not, how would that effect the new log file (if at all it has any implication)

Comment: Hi all, thanks for all your reply, i want to get count of all lines in the file.

Answer (score 2):

Since you only want to count lines, You can keep it simple. Assuming your file name dictates the AFP value

```
static long CountLinesInFile(string fileName,string outputfile)
{
    var afp = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
    var lineCount = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).Length;
    File.WriteAllText(outputfile,$"AFP|QTY{Environment.NewLine}{afp}|{lineCount -1}");
    return lineCount-1;
}
```

Please note you are counting a line less(headers are not counted as in your example). In case the file is different from AFP term, you can use regex to parse the AFP Term from the any line other than the header line in each term. Example Regex for parsing AFP Term

```
new Regex(@"^[0-9]+\|(?<AFP>[a-zA-Z]+)\|[0-9]+\|[a-zA-Z]+$")
```

**Update**

In case your file is pretty large (say 15-20Gb - considering it is a log file), a better approach would be

```
static long CountLinesInFile(string fileName,string outputFileName)
{
    var afp = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
    uint count = 0;
    int query = (int)Convert.ToByte('\n');
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
    {
        int current;
        do
        {
            current = stream.ReadByte();
            if (current == query)
            {
                count++;
                continue;
            }
        } while (current!= -1);
    }

    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(outputFileName, true))
    {
            file.WriteLine($"AFP|QTY{Environment.NewLine}{afp}|{count}");
    }
    return count;
}
```

**Update 2**

To invoke the method for all files in a given folder, you can make use DirectoryInfo.GetFiles, for example

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"E:\TestFolder");
FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.txt"); 
foreach(FileInfo file in Files )
{
  CountLinesInFile(file.FullName,$"{file.FullName}.processed");
}
```

Comment: The answer should use `lines.Length` instead of `lines.Count()`,  although I'm sure array has overridden the Count() to internally call Length, it's a bad habit to rely on an implementation detail

Comment: @Anu Viswan, thanks for your reply, it's work but how do i process all the log files in a folder?

Comment: or even `var count = File.ReadLines(path).Count()` this will not read all the lines into memory at once

Comment: @Naura You can make use of DirectoryInfo.GetFiles to get all files in a folder, I have updated the code with same

Comment: @AnuViswan i have tried your code but somehow i cannot meet the requirement. I have edit my question and can you take a look at it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Naura Assuming from your example that your file name dictate your AFP term, I have updated the code. Please check if it fits your requirement

Comment: @Naura have also added a regex for parsing AFP in case file name doesn't always dictate the AFP term

Answer (score 0):

a simple 2 liner

```
static void CountLines(string path,sting outfile)
{
   var count = File.ReadLines(path).Count();
   File.WriteAllText(outfile, $"AFP|QTY{Environment.NewLine}DDD|{count}");
}
```